# Adjective endings 론 and 로운

Tags: north-korean

Can you please explain if the -론 ending is an old form of -로운 ending?

Is there any difference between 자애론 and 자애로운, 슬기론 and 슬기로운? Generally, what means the verb 롭다?

Comment: Where have you seen 자애론 or 슬기론? Except maybe for poems, I can't think of cases where these are used. (Well of course in speech 자애론 and 자애로운 aren't clearly distinguished, but in writing I think it's always 자애로운.)

Comment: Include the sentenced where you saw this ending. There could be many reasons it says 론 depending on the context  자애론 is most likely a typo

Comment: http://www.dprktoday.com/main.php?type=201&no=12569
민족의 태양이시며 온 겨레의 자애론 어버이이신 위대한 김일성대원수님께서 우리곁을 떠나신 때로부터 22년이 되였다.

And also in aegukka, the national anthem of the DPRK:
슬기론 인민의 이 영광 몸과 맘 다 바쳐 이 조선 길이 받드세

Comment: Hmm, it might be a North Korean specific spelling. As I said, I don't think it's used in South Korea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

론 is only used in north korea
it's like north's accent.
로운 is the correct word in South Korean.